# box2d - more stable stack

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm working at a tower block game using box2d and libgdx.
When i'm adding boxes on on top of each other, after 10 or 15 there is some kind of unstability, and the stack will fall.
What is the best way to make the stack a little more stable?

I've tried using a big angular damping, or giving the boxes a bigger density, but no succes.
Every block has the same physical properties.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using larger boxes, this does not need to effect anything visually. You should already be using meters as your Box2D coordinates and converting that to something more screen relevant.

Comment: I think you are expecting too much. Assuming the boxes are all the same size, the only way you would get a stack that high to stay stable is if they were exactly placed vertically on top of each other, and with perfectly zero angle. I tried this just now with boxes of 1m x 1m and it managed to stabilize and sleep until about 17 boxes. I think this is pretty much how it would be in the real world though right?

Comment: @iforce2d it is, but I just want to make them more stable for a game.. that's all.. 1 meter = 100 pixels in my game

Comment: I guess you could try using some linear damping, might help reduce the tiny movements that eventually grow into larger movements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the unstable stack behavior is inherent to the algorithm Erin's using for position resolution of shapes having two points of contact (at least as per 2.3.2). See my response at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41626448/7410358 for more explanation (including a description of how I modified the algorithm to be more stable).

I tried increasing the sizes of blocks in the Vertical Stack test (of the Box2D Testbed) to see if I could get it to appear any more stable. It did appear to take longer to tip over. So apparently that's a way to make it at least a little more stable.